# Problem on changing Hyperledger Composer version from 0.16.60 to 0.19.14

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am new in blockchain development. Actually i done a demo in composer vertion .16.6. Now i upgrade my composer vertion from 0.16.6 to 0.19.14. And i changed the code in createPeerAdmin.sh file for suitable to vertion 0.19.14. But always showing an error that

Connection profile has no `x-type` property defined. It is not valid for this version of composer

Please help me as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to reset the environment variable for before starting or setup the development server using the following command by changing the fabric version u're going to use specific version from the development servers.
    cd ~/fabric-dev-servers
    export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv11
    ./startFabric.sh
    ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
You can also find better information about the installation of the documentation in the link below:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/development-tools.html

Comment: As @Mohamed mentions above, and for the benefit of others - the connection profile (amongst other things) has changed (ie in 19.x, ie minor release <  0.19.14), with moving from Composer connecting to a Fabric 1.1 environment (instead of Fabric 1.0 / 0.16.x). The normal approach (for Dev) is to tear down the old Fabric, uninstall old Composer modules and stand up a new environment using the Dev tools.  You should also ensure you clear out your old credentials directory under $HOME/.composer when moving to the new version.

Comment: I would encourage you (or anyone) to read the release notes https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.19.14 and follow the docs for 0.19.x (as provided by Mohamed above)